# How to segment in Google Analytics based on Firebase A/B-Test on Android

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am using Firebase and GA4 for my Android App. Currently, I am running an A/B-Test via Firebase.

Is there a way to select a Segment or Audience based on the A/B-Test-Variant? Or do I need to send my own events to identify the variant a user is using?